# Excel: How do I compare the values (for "all match") in column Y for every line with matching values in column X?

Tags: excel-formula

I need to return text "Consistent" when column Y values match, for every line with a matching number in column X.  (and "Inconsistent" when they don't match)

[Image of example table with Z being the formula/result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBkfy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(X:X,X2,Y:Y,Y2)=COUNTIFS(X:X,X2),"Consistent", "Not Consistent")
```

[image]